# Is there any maximum limit to create tun/tap interfaces on a linux machine? Also, what are the parameters that put constraints to the limit?

Tags: linux, communication, ethernet, ns-3, tun-tap

I have been working on the ns-3 (communication network simulator) communication simulator, where there is a  provision called TapBridge mechanism to interface external data sources to the communication nodes. But, for each data source a tap device need to be created on a linux OS bridge, and establish connection with a node in ns-3. I have a requirement of connecting many data sources (say 5000), thence I supposed to create those many tap devices and establish corresponding connections with communication nodes in ns-3. What would be the maximum limit to create tun/tap interfaces on a linux machine? Also, what are the parameters that put constraints to that limit?

Thanks in advance.
-- Gelli

Comment: Have you found anything on this? I'm looking at OpenStack's Neutron and trying to find such configuration there.

Comment: I have not found yet. If you know that can be achieved by Neutron, please do post here the process to establish those many tap devices that can be connected to the ns-3 nodes. - Gelli